# BASH - getting UID on shell script does not work

Tags: bash, shell

Hi I have a question about bash.

and I'm new to it.

I made a file named "test.sh" and its contents is

```
#!/bin/bash
set -x
echo $UID
echo "$UID"
echo "$(id -u)"
```

and the result is blank!!
nothing shows up

However, when i just type "echo $UID" on terminal
it shows "1011"

is there anything i missed for bash?

Please help

UPDATED

bash version is 4.3.11 and I typed "sh test.sh" to execute.

and the result is

```
+ echo

+ echo

+ id -u
+ echo 1011
1011
```

thanks!

Comment: What is your `bash` version? type `bash --version` if you do not know how! Did you try debugging it? Add a `set -x after` the `#!/bin/bash` and run ther script to see what happens

Comment: Does it atleast output two blank lines? Otherwise it would seem that it is not run.

Comment: `$UID` is a Bash variable that is not set under `sh`, that's why your have blank lines.

Comment: If it doesn't work, you can use `uid=$(id -u)`.

Comment: what does `sh` points to ? you may use `ls -lrt /bin/sh`

Comment: `sh` is not the same as `bash`, even if `sh` is a symbolic link to `bash`.

Comment: I thought sh works just like bash

Comment: @EricLee You thought wrong.

Comment: @chepner yes. I was wrong. And now i know that by all of you. Thanks

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`$UID` is a Bash variable that is not set under `sh`, that may be why it outputs blank lines.

Try `bash test.sh` or make your script executable with `chmod u+x test.sh`, the program defined in shebang will then be used (`/bin/bash`)

Comment: Thank you!! I thought "sh" can get bash variable.

Comment: @EricLee, `sh` only guarantees functionality specified in the POSIX sh standard -- it may or may not have more than that, but that can change at any time (ie. if your operating system vendor replaces it with a different implementation). And there are good reason for OS vendors to do that -- ksh, for instance, is much faster than bash at runtime (to be clear, referring to real David Korn ksh, not the clones), whereas ash is smaller, and available built into busybox (to get identical script behavior between a real system and a tiny recovery image).