# tomcat10 home page can not load by typing localhost:8080 error: ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Tags: java, linux, tomcat, raspberry-pi, debian-buster

I had install tomcat10 on my Pi 3B+ Debian full desktop Linux 32bit OS

To make the tomcat10 server successfully instal on my freshly build machine I follow the following recommended settings.

> pi@Home:~ $ java -version
> openjdk version "11.0.9.1" 2020-11-04
> OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.9.1+1-post-Raspbian-1deb10u2)
> OpenJDK Server VM (build 11.0.9.1+1-post-Raspbian-1deb10u2, mixed mode)

Then download and install tomcat10 from:

> wget https://downloads.apache.org/tomcat/tomcat-10/v10.0.2/bin/apache-tomcat-10.0.2.tar.gz

Change the IP address to my local IP address in both following XML files:

> Manager File: ./webapps/manager/META-INF/context.xml Host Manager
> File: ./webapps/host-manager/META-INF/context.xml

```
 <Context antiResourceLocking="false" privileged="true" >
 <CookieProcessor className="org.apache.tomcat.util.http.Rfc6265CookieProcessor"
                  sameSiteCookies="strict" />
  <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteAddrValve"
         allow="127\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+|::1|0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1|192.168.0.16" />
  <Manager sessionAttributeValueClassNameFilter="java\.lang\.(?:Boolean|Integer|Long|Number|String)|org\.apache\.catalina\.filters\.CsrfPreventionFilter\$LruCache(?:\$1)?|java\.util\.(?:Linked)?HashMap"/>
```

After installation complete, I manage to set the environment and start the server

> root@Home:/usr/local/tomcat10# ./bin/startup.sh

Output:

> Using CATALINA_BASE:   /usr/local/tomcat10
> Using CATALINA_HOME:   /usr/local/tomcat10
> Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: /usr/local/tomcat10/temp>
> Using JRE_HOME:        /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-oracle
> Using CLASSPATH:       /usr/local/tomcat10/bin/bootstrap.jar:/usr/local/tomcat10/bin/tomcat->juli.jar
> Using CATALINA_OPTS:
> Tomcat started.

but when I type localhost:8080 I get an error message:

> This site can’t be reached localhost refused to connect.
> Try:

> Checking the connection
> Checking the proxy and the firewall
> ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

As some of the articles on the web suggest to change port 8080 to port 80 in server.xml even trying this option doesn't solve my problem because I have apache webserver running on port 80 by typing localhost:80 it loads the index page for apache webserver

As it is a fresh install and I do not have any firewall installed in my system even on my Router firewall I have enabled TCP/UDP ports 80 and 8080

can anyone please suggest what should I do to load the tomcat index page?

Comment: https://serverfault.com/q/127640/115396

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I have posted this question couple of days ago but I was unable to get an answer so I decided to try a few methods of my own to see if I can resolve the problem. In my case solution, I am posting solved the above issue and I am able to connect to localhost:8080 from my browser window. I have to confess I found this solution by flook I still don't know the logic behind what made it work but it is working.

> root@Home:/usr/local/tomcat10# ./bin/startup.sh

Output:

> Using CATALINA_BASE: /usr/local/tomcat10 Using CATALINA_HOME:
> /usr/local/tomcat10 Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: /usr/local/tomcat10/temp> Using
> JRE_HOME: /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-oracle Using CLASSPATH:
> /usr/local/tomcat10/bin/bootstrap.jar:/usr/local/tomcat10/bin/tomcat->juli.jar
> Using CATALINA_OPTS:
> Tomcat started.

at this stage, I know tomcat is installed successfully and services are all up and running therefore there maybe is something wrong with the browser which may be causing a connectivity issue.

So I took the following steps:

Step No:1

I have click on three dots on the top right-hand side of the Chrome browser window (setting) then I click on more tools then click on clear browsing data.

From the Clear browsing, data window clicked the advance tab and select all times from the drop-down list

Tick all options except Password and other sign-in data and Autofill option

After your selection click the Clear data button

Open new browser window and type localhost:8080

Got unable to connect to the server message

Step NO:2

Now open the My account setting page and from here browse to My activity and clear all previously recorded activities log and turn off all active activity recording sliding switches

Web & App Activity
Location History
YouTube History
Ad personalisation

Open the web browser and typed localhost:8080 (Enter)
still got the same error message

Step NO:3
Go to add the Ad settings, I turned the Ad personalisation setting OFF in past because I didn't want Google to collect my browsing data In your case it might still be ON so I turned it back on for my browser.

now type localhost:8080 surprisingly tomcat10 index page open in my browser window To test if it was Ad setting which was stoping tomcat10 index page to load in browser window I turned Ad personalisation tab OFF again and type localhost:8080 and press Enter
Even the Ad personalisation tab is OFF but this time tomcat10 index page is loaded to the browser window again.

Therefore I am not 100% sure if it was Ad personalisation state which was not allowing the tomcat10 index page to load in the browser window or one of the other previous options which I turned off

To test further I have close all my browsers and then type localhost:8080  in a new browser window and the index page still loading successfully.

This solution is working for me hope it will help other readers too